# Html problem the heading isnt there in the same line as the logo

Tags: html

i wanted to make a website about man utd merch to start i inserted the logo and set everything
but the heading and line i insert are far from the heading .
[the probleme i am faceing](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZfW1R.png)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Man Utd Merch</title>
    <style>
        h1 {
  text-align: center;
}

    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/thumb/7/7a/Manchester_United_FC_crest.svg/800px-Manchester_United_FC_crest.svg.png" width="50" height="50">
    <img align=”left”>
    <h1> Man Utd Merch</h1>
    <hr>
    
    
    
</body>
</html>
```

i tried to places the logo and heading the same line

Comment: `align=”left”` Those are not valid HTML quotation marks.

Comment: you could make the logo `float:left;` or use a flexbox

Comment: How did you try to place them on the same line? I appreciate you're - probably - new to web development, and CSS, but an `<h1>` element has a display of `block` (by default, though this can be adjusted with CSS), which means that it typically puts itself on a new line and takes the full width of that line.

Comment: @DBS For that matter, the `align` attribute there is [obsolete](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/dev/obsolete.html#obsolete).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would do something like this. `display: flex;` allows you to put two (or more) elements in one line. Also I've changed `<hr>` to `border-bottom` and `<h1>` to `<span>` because it's seems more reasonable and clearer in my opinion.

```
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Man Utd Merch</title>
<style>
img {
  align: left;  
}

.content {
  display: flex;
  border-bottom: 1px solid black;
  padding: 10px;
}

.title {
  font-size: 2rem;
  font-weight: bold;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
  <div class="content">
    <img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/thumb/7/7a/Manchester_United_FC_crest.svg/800px-Manchester_United_FC_crest.svg.png" width="50" height="50">
    <span class="title"> Man Utd Merch</span>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```